# WiFi doesn't connects after soft reboot

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, wifi-direct

I'm using Resurrection remix rom on my `Htc One X` (which uses lollipop version: 5.02) but when I use `soft-reboot`  and try to connect with WiFi it says it is connecting but it doesn't connect  and I have to perform a full reboot to connect to WiFi again

PS: I use Resurrection remix rom version : `Resurrection_remix_rom_LP_v5.29`

I tried `re-flashing` ROM performing total `data clean` from `Clockword  Mod Recovery`

Comment: *"I have to perform a full reboot to connect to WiFi again"* -- do you also mean that turning Wi-Fi off ->on -> then connect to a Wi-Fi, also doesn't help after soft-reboot and you must have to do a full reboot?

Comment: @Firelord yes I have to